# Does a ring isomorphic to its opposite always admit an involution?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with identity such that $R\cong R^{\mathrm{op}}$, then is it necessary that $R$ always admits an involution? An involution is an anti-homomorphism $l\colon R\to R$ such that $l\circ l=\mathrm{id}_R$.

Comment: Surely not.... You're asking if whenever there is an anti-isomorphism of $R$, is there also an anti-isomorphism of order 2, i.e. is $R$ a *-ring. Do you have a reason to suspect this would be the case? So many of the rings we work with actually are *-rings that I don't know where to look for good counterexamples though.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I do think this is not true, but I'm wondering a counter-example. It seems not to be so easy to construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling "no involution" yielded this for me as the second result:

> Morandi, Patrick J., Bharath Al Sethuraman, and J-P. Tignol. "Division algebras with an anti-automorphism but with no involution." (2005).

This is interesting because it leads to projective geometries "with duality but not polarity."

The first proof they give is not constructive, but they do follow up with construction of such division rings, at about Corollary 3.6.  The algebra is involved enough that I don't think I can even fit a sketch here.

Comment: Here's the link that works for now: http://www.csun.edu/~asethura/papers/AntiAutNoInv.pdf